# MLE first order conditions

Tags: mle

I need to derive the first order conditions for the following maximum likelihood. Can anyone help?

I observe the total cost y as follow:
[tot-cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9pTc.png)

where x are quantities and p are prices.
If the prices are drawn from a bivariate normal distribution as follow:
[joint normal price dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzja5.png)
Then y has the following normal
[y normal dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNQzN.png)
now I want to estimate the var-cov matrix of prices (p1 and p2) given the following pdf:
[pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjJEz.png)
What are the FOC for the five parameters?

I have the FOC for the mus. I need to find the formulas for var-cov matrix. I know that i can get the mus using ols. I am not sure how to get the sigmas

Comment: I want to use code in R. If there is no closed form. Is there a way to estimate the code using MLE?